# Corrupted video files after moving to sd card

Tags: filesystem, sd-card

Hi I am new to Ubuntu and I have recently been getting this problem. When I move video files to a SD card they get corrupted and show 0 bytes. I have been getting this problem since I used:

```
echo $((16*1024*1024)) > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_bytes
echo $((48*1024*1024)) > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_bytes
```

I was on 19.04 at that time and the system would hang up while I tried to move large files to my SD card. So I tried those two lines above.

Since then, I have been getting this problem.

Is there any way I can revert those two commands?
Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

These settings are not persistent. A reboot will reset to the default value of 0, which you can verify with:

```
cat /proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_bytes
cat /proc/sys/vm/dirty_bytes
```

Trying to [reset these values to their default of 0 has no effect](https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB/issues/267#issuecomment-574228289). As of kernel 4.4, doing so [fails with `EINVAL`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/e260ad01f0aa9e96b5386d5cd7184afd949dc457).